# cannot access webservice made in java 14 using application made in java 7

Tags: web-services, ssl, java-7, tls1.2, sslhandshakeexception

My application is developed in java 7 and i have to access a "https" web service which is developed in java 14.I am getting "Received fatal alert: handshake_failure"

this is stacktrace

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1592616408 bytes = { 12, 135, 232, 24, 158, 109, 182, 182, 90, 77, 217, 233, 239, 161, 116, 121, 128, 150, 234, 201, 224, 14, 34, 171, 199, 213, 212, 98 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: collabdds.gov.in]
***
http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-7, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 246
http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-7, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-7, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-7, called closeSocket()
http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-7, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-7, called close()
http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-7, called closeInternal(true)
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
```

My code is

```
private static SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory() {
    try 
    {
        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
        new X509TrustManager() {
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {      }
        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {      }
        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
        }
        }
        };
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());
        SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}
```

somewhere in another function i have written following

```
((HttpsURLConnection)conn).setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory());
```

this is my server's VM arguments [image: this is my server's VM arguments]

In my jre7\lib\security
i have update local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar

what am i missing . Do i need to add cipher suits or it can be browser problem ( i am using firefox 84.0) or something else. I cannot upgrade to java8.

Answer (score 0):

According to [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=collabdds.gov.in) the server collabdds.gov.in supports only four TLS1.2 ciphers (TLS1.3 is also supported by the server but not supported by Java 7 at all):

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

Your Java version does not support any of those ciphers, hence the connection can not be established and the TLS handshake fails.

Java 7 is a dead horse when it comes to online and web services. If you want to access this server I strongly recommend to you to switch to Java 8. Or you have to use a local proxy that performs the "HTTPS translation" from recent TLS1.2 ciphers to your old and insecure Java version.

In my opinion you should take this to really consider upgrading to Java 8. Earlier or later you have to do this anyway.

Note that the used web browser is totally irrelevant for problems where your application acts as a client for a backend-service. Only if the web browser would directly connects to the back-end server this would matter.

Comment: I cannot switch to java8, because by calling web service I am adding some functionality in live old web application. Please can you tell how to use a local proxy that performs the "HTTPS translation" from recent TLS1.2 ciphers

Comment: @IlaVerma You could install a local proxy like Mitmproxy. It makes HTTPS interception, hence it makes it's own handshake to the server. As it uses Python it is not bound to your "Java 7 restriction" and therefore can provide different ciphers. mitmproxy is just an example, other proxies that do HTTPS interception should also work. The important part is just that the proxy supports at least one cipher supported by your Java 7 list and one from the used server. In your Java app you then have to configure every request to that server to use that local proxy.

Comment: thank you for giving a solution. But I don't think  my company will allow me to install proxy in server. Can nothing be done using coding or adding some jars , certificates?

Comment: @IlaVerma I have a clear statement for your boss regarding that topic: "If you are using unsupported long-dead software you have to face the consequences. Everything comes at a price."

Comment: -thank you i discusswith my boss if we can upgrade to java 8